# Always launching flash player in secondary monitor and full screen mode

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash, flashdevelop

I am trying to set the location of Flash Player launch location to my secondary monitor connected using a VGA cable and I want to launch it always in FullScreen mode. After couple of searches, I found one link which relates to this topic:
http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=6658

But it doesn't seem to work for me. How do I set the x,y co-ordinates of flash player when it is launching as a new process ?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe air has a Screen class to handle this.  To help you out, there is an open source project on Google code that wraps this and handles some of the basics:

http://code.google.com/p/airscreenmanageras3/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jason. I am looking for adjusting the x,y location of Flash Player. My application is not using Adobe AIR, it just launches inside Flash Player as a Projector.